# Using Dictionaries instead of 2D array

Tags: python, python-3.x

Give an array and suppose I want to calculate the sum of all subarrays.
So I can do the following:

```
dict = {}
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(i, n):
        dict[(i,j)] = ...    # calculate the sum
```

Here I am using the dictionaries to store the sum for each pair of indexes.
An alternative would be to use python 2D arrays.
Which is a better approach? Are there any pros and cons of using dictionaries?

Although I find it easier to use a dictionary without worrying about the weird syntax for 2D arrays and specifying the rows and columns.

Comment: 1) Dictionaries are much slower, but their keys can have types other than integers, see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries . 2) `weird syntax for 2D arrays` - better get used to it (and I hope you understand what exactly `a[i][j]` means). 3) Depending on the rest of the code, you may want to use `numpy` arrays.

Comment: Both approaches can be useful for a specific task. So if you don't state your real purpose, you will get subjective opinions instead of answers.

Comment: @Vitalizzare In the use case where I want to store the subarray sum, is the dict approach a good one?  Could you also provide an alternate approach using arrays or lists? I am really confused about the difference between arrays and lists in python. A sample code for calculating the subarray sum using arrays or lists could help

Comment: What is **subarray** in your case an how are you gonna use **dict**?

Comment: @Vitalizzare any continuous segment of the given array.

Comment: IMO If you want to use each pair of indices as an inseparable unit, then `dict` seems more appropriate. If separate iterations or operations are expected over each index, then `list` may be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

using 2D array is faster.
you can compute the time using time.time()  function to execute the two procedures a big difference